# Get all followings using LINQ to Twitter

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-phone, linq-to-twitter

I've just started a Windows Phone app, and I need to get all the user's followings.
I tried [this](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Listing%20Friends&referringTitle=Listing%20Social%20Graphs) :

```
SharedState.Authorizer = pinAuth;
ITwitterAuthorizer auth = SharedState.Authorizer;
TwitterContext twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

var friendList =
    (from friend in twitterCtx.SocialGraph
        where friend.Type == SocialGraphType.Friends && friend.ScreenName == "_TDK"
        select friend)
    .SingleOrDefault();

List<String> Followings;
foreach (var id in friendList.ScreenName)
{
    Followings.Add(id.ToString());
}
```

But **friendlist** is always *null* and, obviously, the `foreach` does not like that and throws an `exception`.

Could someone help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to iterate over the IDs collection, like this:

```
foreach (var id in friendList.IDs)
{
    Followings.Add(id.ToString());
}
```

You need to make async calls with Silverlight-based apps, including Windows Phone. Here's an example of how you can refactor the query:

```
var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);

(from social in twitterCtx.SocialGraph
 where social.Type == SocialGraphType.Followers &&
       social.ScreenName == "JoeMayo"
 select social)
.MaterializedAsyncCallback(asyncResponse =>
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
     {
         if (asyncResponse.Status != TwitterErrorStatus.Success)
         {
              MessageBox.Show(
                  "Error during query: " + 
                  asyncResponse.Exception.Message);
              return;
         }

         SocialGraph social = asyncResponse.State.SingleOrDefault();

         SocialListBox.ItemsSource = social.IDs;
     }));
```

The MaterializedAsyncCallback manages the callback from Twitter. Notice how I use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to marshal the call back onto the UI thread as the callback is on a worker thread. On the asyncResponse callback parameter, use Status to see if there is an error and use State to get the data if the query is successful.

Comment: friendList is null, it does not change anything, the problem is here I think, but I can't find what's the matter... Maybe the twittercontext ?  
`(from friend in twitterCtx.SocialGraph
            where friend.Type == SocialGraphType.Friends && friend.ScreenName == "_TDK"
            select friend)
        .SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: @user2877820 If you would like to add additional information, please do so via a comment, so the author of the post can determine whether to include it or not. The exception here is Community Wiki posts, which are 'anonymous' community-managed answers/questions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I solved this way (I know it's not the best way)

```
public void getProfile(MyProgressBar myprogressbar)
{
    var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
    {
        Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
        {
            ConsumerKey = GlobalVariables.ConsumerKey,
            ConsumerSecret = GlobalVariables.ConsumerSecret,
            AccessToken = GlobalVariables.AccessToken,
            OAuthToken = GlobalVariables.AccessTokenSecret
        }
    };

    using (var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth, "https://api.twitter.com/1/", "https://search.twitter.com/"))
    {
        //Log
        twitterCtx.Log = Console.Out;

        var queryResponse = (from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
                             where tweet.Type == StatusType.User && tweet.ScreenName == GlobalVariables.ScreenName
                             select tweet);

        queryResponse.AsyncCallback(tweets =>
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                var publicTweets = (from tweet in tweets
                                    select tweet).FirstOrDefault();
                s.TwitterName = publicTweets.User.Name.ToString();
                s.TwitterScreenName = "@" + GlobalVariables.ScreenName;
                s.TwitterDescription = publicTweets.User.Description.ToString();
                s.TwitterStatus = publicTweets.User.StatusesCount.ToString() + " Tweets / " + publicTweets.User.FriendsCount.ToString() + " Following / " + publicTweets.User.FollowersCount.ToString() + " Followers";
                s.TwitterImage = publicTweets.User.ProfileImageUrl.ToString();

                myprogressbar.ShowProgressBar = false;

            })).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works without error, but publicTweets is null, and i can't get the screenName etc

Comment: @TDK yeah screenname null it's kind of bug of linq 2 twitter, but the resta of datas for me works... did you solve definitely with joe mayo solution?